# Solve $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ , $u(x,0)=1-2x+3x^2$, $t\gt0,-\infty\lt x\lt +\infty$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ , $u(x,0)=1-2x+3x^2$, $t\gt0,-\infty\lt x\lt +\infty$

For $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ ,we can get $u(x,t)=f(x-t)+g(x+t)$ and $u(x,0)=1-2x+3x^2=f(x)+g(x)$, what's the next? Now do we need more information to get an explict solution?

Comment: $u_t(x,0)=\phi(x)$ ???

Comment: so we do need such a condition such that we could complete the left work?

Answer (score 1):

$$
u(x,t) = f(x-t)+g(x+t)
$$

$$
u(x,0) = f(x)+g(x) = 1-2x+3x^2
$$

so making $f = g$ we have

$$
f(x) = \frac 12\left(1-2x+3x^2\right)
$$

and finally

$$
u(x,t) = \frac 12\left(1-2(x-t)+3(x-t)^2\right) + \frac 12\left(1-2(x+t)+3(x+t)^2\right)
$$

or

$$
u(x,t) = \frac 12\left(1+3t^2+x(3x-2)\right)
$$

Comment: Why can we make such an assumption $f=g$?

Comment: $f, g$ are general functions including the possibility $f = g$